# How do I detect a click event on a google map through an overlay?

Tags: google-maps

My problem is that I have a circle map overlay but I want to be able to move the circle by clicking the map to set the new center, the actual problem is that when I click on the overlay and call my method 'setCenter(overlay, latlng) ' , I get undefined latlang and a valid overlay.

here is an example that can illustrate the problem, if you click the map a polygon is drawn and if you click inside the polygon no new polygon is drawn, if you click anywhere else on the map a polygon is drawn
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/polygon-simple.html

I want to be able to click the polygon and draw a new one making them overlap

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All you need to do is to set the `clickable: false` option in the `GPolygon` constructor, as in the following example ([GPolygonOptions: API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GPolygonOptions)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Non Clickable Polygon Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" 
              type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body onunload="GUnload()">
   <div id="map" style="width: 450px; height: 300px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);

      GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latlng) {
         var lat = latlng.lat();
         var lon = latlng.lng();
         var latOffset = 0.01;
         var lonOffset = 0.01;
         var polygon = new GPolygon([
            new GLatLng(lat, lon - lonOffset),
            new GLatLng(lat + latOffset, lon),
            new GLatLng(lat, lon + lonOffset),
            new GLatLng(lat - latOffset, lon),
            new GLatLng(lat, lon - lonOffset)
         ], "#f33f00", 5, 1, "#ff0000", 0.2, { clickable: false });

         map.addOverlay(polygon);
      });
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot with evidence:

[image: Google Maps Non Clickable Polygon Demo]

Note that the `click(overlay: GOverlay, latlng: GLatLng, overlaylatlng: GLatLng)` event passes different arguments based on the context of the click, and whether or not the click occured on a clickable overlay. If the click does not occur on a clickable overlay, the `overlay` argument is `null` and the `latlng` argument contains the geographical coordinates of the point that was clicked. If the user clicks on an overlay that is clickable, the `overlay` argument contains the overlay object, while the `overlaylatlng` argument contains the coordinates of the clicked overlay ([Source: API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.click)).