# Clicking inside a polygon in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, click, overlay

The included JavaScript snippet is supposed to do the following:

1. As the user clicks on the map, initialize headMarker and draw a circle (polygon) around it
2. As the user clicks inside the circle, initialize tailMarker and draw the path between these two markers

1 is happening as expected. But as the user clicks inside the circle, in the `function(overlay,point)`, `overlay` is non-null while `point` is null. Because of this, the code fails to initialize tailMarker.

Can someone tell me a way out.

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay,point) {
    if (isCreateHeadPoint) {
        // add the head marker
        headMarker = new GMarker(point,{icon:redIcon,title:'0'});
        map.addOverlay(headMarker);
        isCreateHeadPoint = false;
        // draw the circle
        drawMapCircle(point.lat(),point.lng(),1,'#cc0000',2,0.8,'#0',0.1);
    } else {
        // add the tail marker
        tailMarker = new GMarker(point,{icon:greenIcon,title:''});
        map.addOverlay(tailMarker);
        isCreateHeadPoint = true;
        // load thes path from head to tail
        direction.load("from:" + headMarker.getPoint().lat()+ ", " + 
                        headMarker.getPoint().lng()+ " " +
                       "to:" + tailMarker.getPoint().lat() + "," +
                        tailMarker.getPoint().lng(), 
                       {getPolyline:true}); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to set the `clickable: false` option in the `GPolygon` constructor of your circle. The following is an example that I used to answer [another similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488192/how-do-i-detect-a-click-event-on-a-google-map-through-an-overlay):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Clicking Inside a Polygon</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" 
              type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body onunload="GUnload()">
   <div id="map" style="width: 450px; height: 300px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);

      GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latlng) {
         var lat = latlng.lat();
         var lon = latlng.lng();
         var latOffset = 0.01;
         var lonOffset = 0.01;
         var polygon = new GPolygon([
            new GLatLng(lat, lon - lonOffset),
            new GLatLng(lat + latOffset, lon),
            new GLatLng(lat, lon + lonOffset),
            new GLatLng(lat - latOffset, lon),
            new GLatLng(lat, lon - lonOffset)
         ], "#f33f00", 5, 1, "#ff0000", 0.2, { clickable: false });

         map.addOverlay(polygon);
      });
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot of the above example:

[image: Google Maps Clicking Inside a Polygon]

I used diamonds instead of circles, because they are easier to draw in the v2 API. Note that the `latlng` parameter of the `click` listener would have been null if the polygons were not created with the `clickable: false` option.

Comment: Great thanks. It works. Its weird how you have to set clickable:"false" for enabling the click (I had thought it will be clickable:true)

Comment: @amarsh-anand: Yes, basically by setting it `clickable: false` you're telling the API that a click that happens to be on a polygon should be handled as a click on the map, instead of a click on the polygon.