# Transfer click from google map overlay to map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, onclicklistener, polygon, eventtrigger

I would like to get the map to behave normally as if the color overlay (polygon) was not there. I would like to be able to click on local listings or anything displayed normally by the map. I tried the following but with no luck ...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon, 'click', function(e) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(myPolygon.getMap(), 'click', e);
});
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: look at the answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488192/how-do-i-detect-a-click-event-on-a-google-map-through-an-overlay

Comment: Thanks ;) Working fine now.

Comment: I just noticed when cickable is false the onmouseover event is not working anymore ... Any solution for that?