# Google Maps click event on a layer with lower zIndex

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am displaying a marker with a circle around it on a Google Map. When the user clicks another point on the map, the marker with the circle are moved to that point. However, I can't figure out how to let the user click on the map in the area covered by the circle. I'd like to set the zIndex of the circle behind the map for clicking purposes but still have it visible.

Any approaches to suggest?  Thanks in advance.

Here's my code if you want a look:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom:8,center: new google.maps.LatLng(userLat,userLng)});
var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value*1000;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(userLat.toFixed(3),userLng.toFixed(3)),map: map,icon: 'images/markers/9.png'});
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({map: map,radius:distance,strokeColor:'rgb(65,130,245)',strokeOpacity:0.5,fillColor:'rgb(65,130,245)',fillOpacity:0.2,strokeWeight:1});
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
    marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
    document.getElementById("latlng").value = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + ","  + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("latlngX").style.visibility="visible";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can: add this CSS to the object you want to turn uninteractable: `pointer-event: none`.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

edit:
The answer accepted at this question was the correct solution:
[How do I detect a click event on a google map through an overlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488192/how-do-i-detect-a-click-event-on-a-google-map-through-an-overlay)

Comment: this doesn't work because the zIndex of the polygon is higher than the map.

Comment: Does this answer help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488192/how-do-i-detect-a-click-event-on-a-google-map-through-an-overlay ?

Comment: Yep, that does it!  Thanks.